# Geofence doesn't work when the app is killed

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, android-geofence

I know that the question is already asked, but I tried so many suggested solutions but it doesn't work.

My code for geofence works when app is running, but once the app is killed the notification doesn't appear anymore even when BroadcastReceiver

You can find here the code associated to the activity, btn_reservation is the button that starts adding the geofence.

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<Status> {

public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 500
private List<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Button btn_reservation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    btn_reservation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reserver);

    mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

    mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()

            .setRequestId("1")

            .setCircularRegion(
                    MapsActivity.getLatitude(),
                    MapsActivity.getLongitude(),
                    GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
            )
            .setExpirationDuration(GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
            .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            .build());


    // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }


    btn_reservation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Google API Client not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                try {
                    LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                            mGoogleApiClient,
                            getGeofencingRequest(),
                            getGeofencePendingIntent()
                    ).setResultCallback(DetailsActivity.this); // Result processed in onResult().
                } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
                    // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission unused ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    });

}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent("ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");

    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            getApplicationContext(),
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        System.out.println("My lat " +String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        System.out.println("My lon " +String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onResult(Status status) {
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
        System.out.println("Geofences Added");
    } else {
        System.out.println(status.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

And this is my `GeofenceReceiver.java`

```
public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
Context context;

Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;

    broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (event.hasError()) {
        handleError(intent);
    } else {
        handleEnterExit(intent);
    }

}

private void handleError(Intent intent){
    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    // Get the error code
    int errorCode = event.getErrorCode();

    // Get the error message
    String errorMessage = LocationServiceErrorMessages.getErrorString(
            context, errorCode);

    // Log the error
    Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
           "geofence_transition_error_detail"+
                    errorMessage);

    // Set the action and error message for the broadcast intent
    broadcastIntent
            .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR)
            .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, errorMessage);

    // Broadcast the error *locally* to other components in this app
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(
            broadcastIntent);
}


private void handleEnterExit(Intent intent) {

    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    int transition = event.getGeofenceTransition();

    // Test that a valid transition was reported
    if ((transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
            || (transition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)) {

        // Post a notification
        List<Geofence> geofences = event
                .getTriggeringGeofences();
        String[] geofenceIds = new String[geofences.size()];
        String ids = TextUtils.join(GeofenceUtils.GEOFENCE_ID_DELIMITER,
                geofenceIds);
        int tran = Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER;
        String transitionType = String.valueOf(tran);

        // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
        broadcastIntent
                .setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_TRANSITION)
                .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context)
                .sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        // Log the transition type and a message
        Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, transitionType + ": " + ids);
        Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text));

        // In debug mode, log the result
        Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, "transition");

        // An invalid transition was reported
    } else {
        // Always log as an error
        Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG,
                "geofence_transition_invalid_type"
                       + transition);
    }

    sendNotification(String.valueOf(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER), "here");
}

private void sendNotification(String transitionType, String locationName) {

    // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TicketActivity.class);

    // Construct a task stack
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

    // Adds the main Activity to the task stack as the parent
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(TicketActivity.class);

    // Push the content Intent onto the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
    PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent = stackBuilder
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions
    // >= 4
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context);

    // Set the notification contents
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_0)
            .setContentTitle(transitionType + ": " + locationName)
            .setContentText(
                    context.getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
            .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

    // Get an instance of the Notification manager
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Issue the notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

    System.out.println("in radius");
  }
}
```

And this is my receiver in the manifest

```
 <receiver android:name="tn.odc.noq.receiver.GeofenceReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="tn.odc.noq.receiver.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE"/>
      <category android:name="tn.odc.noq.receiver" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with geofences from scratch it's really hard, I've been tried for along time do this, but I didn't getting a good stub. So i've adopted to use some libs

Here some awesome libs:

[Smart-location-lib](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib)

Ex:

```
GeofenceModel mestalla = new GeofenceModel.Builder("id_mestalla")
    .setTransition(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER)
    .setLatitude(39.47453120000001)
    .setLongitude(-0.358065799999963)
    .setRadius(500)
    .build();
```

[Android-rxgeofence](https://github.com/esafirm/android-rxgeofence)

```
 RxGeoFence.with(this) //context
        .dbUrl(GEO_FIRE_DB) //String
        .geoFenceSource(...) // rx.Observable<List<Place>>
        .locationSource(...) // rx.Observable<LatLng>
        .build()
        .subscribe(geoFenceEvent -> {
         // do what you wanna do with the event
     });
```

[Android-ReactiveLocation](https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation)

```
 Geofence geofence = new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId("GEOFENCE")
                    .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, radius)
                    .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build();
```

I actually indicate use libs as there are a large number of developers working to solve all the problems, and negotiations exception.